# Converting several files with Multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have seeked for an answer on this site but didn't find out. My problem is that I want to convert several files from a format to another in python. I would like to convert 4 files simultaneously. I have already made a code with process keyword from the multiprocessing library, it works, but it uses several processes to convert files one by one, which is not what I want. I tried to convert them simultaneously with this code:

```
def convert_all_files (directoryName):
  directoryName = r'Here I set my directory name C:\...'
  files2=[]
  pool=mp.Pool(4)
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directoryName):
    for f in files:
      f1=f
      path1=path        
      files2.append((path1,f1))
  for j in range(0, len(files2)):
    pool.apply_async(convert, (files2[j][0],files2[j][1]))
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

My problem is that the code runs, but the function convert is not executed, and the code freezes at the line pool.join() (I use this technique to gain a lot of time because conversion is very long, and when I run this code, the conversion is instantaneous and doesn't work.)

I use the function defined above in another file. I import my module and call the function.

Does anyone has an Idea?
thanks

Comment: Your code indentation seems wrong, can you please check it ?

Comment: Hello! thanks for your reply. Y es, the code identation turned bad when I paste the code on this forum. I set another one righ now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, without the limitations of 4 conversion at the same time.

```
def convert_all_files(directoryName):
    for folder, subs, files in os.walk(directoryName):
        for filename in files:
            p = Process(target=convert, args=(folder, filename))
            p.start()
```

If you need the limitation, here is a solution, but I am not sure this is the best:

```
def convert_all_files(directoryName):
    process_count = 0
    for folder, subs, files in os.walk(directoryName):
        for filename in files:
            p = Process(target=convert, args=(folder, filename))
            p.start()

            # Maybe not the better way to handle it
            process_count = process_count + 1
            if process_count % 4 == 0:
                p.join()
```